# how to access javascript variable in global.asax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript variable in a page default.aspx

```
var name="user1"

window.location="test.aspx"
```

this page will submit to test.aspx and in global.asax while firing Application_BeginRequest event ,i need to access the variable "name". i need to do this without cookies. 
Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: How will it submit? Where is that mysterious variable, in your java source?

Comment: OK, next question: Why do you need to submit a variable whoose value is already known serverside (to send it to the client in a script-tag)?

Answer (score 1):

`var name="user1"` is a javascript variable that you could access inside `Application_BeginRequest` from the Request object assuming you have passed it to the `test.aspx` page when redirecting:

```
var name = "user1";
window.location.href = 'test.aspx?name=' + encodeURIComponent(name);
```

and then:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = HttpContext.Current.Request["name"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        // the name variable was present in the request => do something with it
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case use a `<form>` with `method="POST"`. But bear in mind that if this is some sensitive information it should not even be in your javascript code. If you are doing some sort of authentication I would recommend you using Forms Authentication instead of reinventing some wheels here.

Comment: im using window.location for navigating to next page. How can i use POST here?

Comment: You can't. `window.location.href` uses GET. If you want to use POST you will have to use a `<form>` with `method="POST"` or an AJAX request. But as I said, if this is some sensitive information you shouldn't be doing anything like that at all because a malicious user could forge any request and replace the value with whatever he wants even if you are using POST. So don't be fooled into thinking that if the value is not in the query string you have it secured.

Comment: i need to use window.location in this scenario. then what is the use of creating a form here? anyway im not posting the page..please explain..

Comment: If you need to use `window.location` then the only way is to pass the value as a query string parameter. That's how window.location works. That's what a GET request means. The use of creating a form is that it allows you to use a different verb such as POST which in turn allows you to send values in the POST body, not in the query string.

Comment: yes.its true. any other way like URL rewriting to hide the querystring in the url?

Comment: No, url rewriting works on the server. You have the valueon the client (javascript). So you will have to send it to the server. There are 2 standard ways: GET or POST. GET users query string, POST uses variables in the POST body.

Comment: if i send the value using querystring, from global.asax is it possible to rewrite the url without querystring?

Comment: No, Global.asax runs on the server. This value needs to reach the server from the client. There are 2 ways to do this: GET or POST. Damn, I get the feeling that I am repeating myself and we are turning around in circles here :-)

Answer (score 1):

If by *"submit"* you mean perform a `POST` or `GET` request then you'll need to pass `name` as a `url-encoded` string to the server as a form `POST` or as a querystring parameter in a `GET` request.

Then, in the `Application_BeginRequest` access the `Request` from the `Current` `HttpContext`

Comment: im using window.location to submit to the next page. But i dont want to show the querystring in URL

Comment: that is not the way you submit a `POST` request, changing `window.location` performs a "redirect" using `GET`.